# How do I show that $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = O(n^3)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computational-complexity

Do I have to know the formula for the summation? Why?

Comment: We cannot prove something that is wrong. $$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} i^{2} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \mathcal{O}(n^{3}).$$

Comment: @sos440 It's supposed to be $O(n^3)$.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. Anyway, you can refer to that exact formula. Of course there are several other ways of estimating it.

Comment: The intuitive idea is that you have a sum of $n$ elements each of magnitude around $n^2$, therefore the total sum seems to be of the order $n^3$. The exact formula supports our initial guess.

Comment: $1^2+2^2+\cdots +n^2\le n^2+n^2+\cdots +n^2 = n^3.$

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is only to find an approximate bound, there are several tricks: Let $s > 0$.

1. Using the largest summand, we get
   $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{s} \leq n \cdot n^{s} = n^{s+1}.$$
2. To make the constant small,
   $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{s}
   \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{k}^{k+1} x^{s} \, ds 
   \leq \int_{0}^{n+1} x^{s} \, ds
   = \frac{(n+1)^{s+1}}{s+1}. $$
   Indeed, this is not far from the truth as
   $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{s} = \frac{n^{s+1}}{s+1} + \mathcal{O}(n^{s}). $$

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand anything you wrote...

Comment: @user6607, For (1), each $k^{s}$ ($1 \leq k \leq n$) is less then or equal to $n^{s}$. So you can bound term by term by $n^{s}$ and you end up with the sum of $n$ copies of $n^{s}$, i.e., $n \cdot n^{s} = n^{s+1}$.

Comment: What does that have to do with $O(n^3)$?

Comment: You may want to consider the case $s = 2$ and recall what the big-Oh notation means.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you do not know the formula for the summation.  But you do know the following:

$$p(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n i^2\\
p(n+1) - p(n) = (n+1)^2 = O(n^2)\\
(n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n + 1 = O(n)\\
2(n+1)-1 - (2n - 1) = 2 = O(1)$$

This is only an intuitive approach; a more rigorous approach could make use of binomial forms and note that $p(n)$ must have a term $\binom n 3$ in it, therefore $p(n) = O(n^3)$.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in that example? It's really hard for me to follow the logic.

Comment: This is a series of differences between one value of a function and the value immediately preceding it.  We take the original sum as the first function and note that the difference between two terms is just one of the sum terms, and we also make note of the order of this difference.  Then we take another difference based on the first one and note the same things, and that the order of the function has decreased.

Comment: The main point is to notice that in one direction the order is decreasing, so that we could say that in the other direction the order would be increasing.  In particular, this should be an intuitive way to see that $O(p(n))=O(n^3)$.  As I said, writing everything using binomial terms would prove this result conclusively.